# r - compare elements of list from one dataframe to values from another dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, compare

I'm trying to compare two datasets of which the first one is standard dataframe and the other is a dataframe with a list column. My goal is to compare every element from the list in the list column `var34` with the two variables in `df_i` called `var1` and `var2`.

In the case when they are equal I would like the element of the list which is equal (equal to `var1` and `var2`) and the `flag` variable in the final dataset.

Is it possible to do this in R without using any type of `dplyr::join` and no rearranging of the variables?

The ideal solution would be a loop that goes row by row through the `df_i` dataset and checks which element in which row in `df_list` satisfies the condition of equality.

Reproducible example:

```
# dataframe to be compared
df_i <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), var1 = c(1,2,4,6,4,2), var2 = c(2,4,5,2,1,6))

# dataframe with list column to compare to df_i
df_list <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  var34 = I(list(c(4,7),c(1,2),c(1,5),c(1,3),c(4,1),c(1,3),c(6,2),c(3,9),c(2,6)))) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% summarise(var34 = list(var34)) %>% mutate(flag = c("c", "b", "f"))

# desired output
df_e <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3), 
  var1 = c(1,2,4,6,4,2), 
  var2 = c(2,4,5,2,1,6), 
  flag = c(NA, "c", NA, "b", "b", "f"), 
  var5 = I(list(NA,c(1,2),NA,c(4,1),c(6,2),c(2,6)))))
```

Comment: What is the issue with `join` solutions?  Here, we assume that the 'id's have to match?

Comment: @akrun I prefer a loop solution since I want to check other conditions, not just equality. I need to check other conditions with the row before and the row after not just the current row. Is it possible to write a loop that will do that ?